# UIScrollView scrolling, when something deleted?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll

I have elements that are able to be deleted in a UIScrollView. When I delete something at the  bottom of the scroll view, i do not want to scroll to top, i want to stay at the area that i deleted the element.

I have searched for this, but there is no solution yet,

Do you have any?

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Deleting an element from the `UIScrollView` does not byitself perform any scrolling - it does not change the `contentOffset`.

Comment: i need set scroll offset where i delete the element?

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect Bound = [self.myViewName bounds]; // such like UIButton, UITextFiled .. etc.
CGPoint pt = Bound.origin;

[self.scrollView setContentOffset:pt animated:YES];
```

Also [Read This Documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset%3aanimated%3a)

Comment: could you please a little bit explain

Comment: what you element that you want to delete ?? i mean it is UIBUtton, UItextFiled // ??

Comment: it is uiview which consists of subviews

Comment: i have more than one of this view, can i do multiplication, like row*[myview bounds]

Comment: here write name element which you want to delete :) and then after delete this element

Comment: my element name is doktorKutu, but i am creating it dynamically when a button is tapped. and removing when the cancel button is tapped on it. i have more than one row in the scrollview, and more than one doktorKutu in a row

Comment: @iPatel: bounds will give you origin of {0,0} - you need frame to get the real origin.

Answer (score 0):

If you (according to your comment) want to scroll to the 
position of the component being deleted you can do this:

```
//get the frame of component being deleted

CGRect frameOfDeletedView = viewBeingDeleted.frame;

//set the content offset

[theScrollView scrollRectToVisible:frameOfDeletedView animated:NO];

//remove the component

//...
```